# MacOS what process is using port 8888

Tags: mac

How can I tell which process is using port 8888? 
I have an NKE and my process is needing to connect to it. Every now and then I get bind socket error, 127.0.0.1:8888 is in use...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you really on MacOS? Props, man.

Comment: Please do not cross-post on multiple sites - decide which site is best for your question, and then write the question for that site's audience. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

@Somantra's answer is close, but won't quite work.  Try:

```
sudo lsof -i:8888
```

sudo may be needed so lsof can see processes not owned by you; also, grepping lsof's output will fail unless you search for the service name associated with port 8888 (it's "ddi-tcp-1").

Comment: great now that I know what process is owning that, can I just kill it so that application can use that port to communicate with my NKE? Will ddi-tcp-1 just pick another port to use? and why do i only run into this problem on OS Mac 1.0.5?

Comment: It depends on what process is using the port, and how that process is managed -- if it's something controlled by launchd, it's probably configured to relaunch if it exits for any reason.  What's the process using it? [Here](http://serverfault.com/questions/285078/how-can-i-prevent-a-process-from-running-under-mac-osx-10-6/285088#285088) is an example of tracking down where a launchd item is being controlled and shutting it down.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for.

```
lsof | grep ":8888"
```

NOTE: Thanks @Gordon Davisson, I forgot about the alias I added which made the command above work for me.

```
alias lsof='sudo lsof -Pni4 | grep LISTEN'
```